# Appcenter android analytics can't establish connection to the console

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

Due to some issues I can not use firebase analytics so I am trying to switch to microsoft appcenter analytics.

I have created a new android project, followed the detailed instructions on the overview page but I do not get any analytics data or crash data when I push a debug build on a phone from android studio and manually trigger a crash. The overview page is still showing me the instructions so I imagine that the connection was not successful.

What I have done so far:

- added dependencies on build.gradle
- initiated analytics/crashlytics at the App class
- added on manifest this `android:fullBackupContent="@xml/appcenter_backup_rule"`

Here is the xml for the rules, I got it from the detailed documentation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="AppCenter.xml"/>
    <exclude domain="database" path="com.microsoft.appcenter.persistence"/>
    <exclude domain="database" path="com.microsoft.appcenter.persistence-journal"/>
    <exclude domain="file" path="error" tools:ignore="FullBackupContent"/>
    <exclude domain="file" path="appcenter" tools:ignore="FullBackupContent"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Did you create appcenter_backup_rule.xml file under Resources folder and put that XML rules in that file?

Comment: Apparently the first connection takes times and that was the reason.